# Automated framework for Rails application, with some Angular and embedded iFrames?

Tags: angular, automation, rspec, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

My company has a Rails application, with one section of functionality built in Angular. There's also a portion of the app that is embedded iFrames that point to a Looker dashboards (Looker is a data aggregation/visualization tool).

We have a strong foundation of Rspec unit tests, and a fair amount of e2e tests in Rspec as well. However, we can't test the iFrames locally because they point to a remote source. I'm hoping to implement an automated framework that can handle all of the following:

- Rails functionality
- Angular functionality
- embedded iFrames

Does anyone have any strong recommendations/tips/warnings? Thanks!

Almost all of our basic Ruby functionality is covered by Rspec tests. However the Angular portion of the app is very loosely covered, and the iFrames are not covered at all.

Comment: I don't know about the iframes, but I would try looking into cypress